# Fork an expo module and how to maintain it

Tags: git, react-native, expo, expo-av

As you probably already know Expo is react native developer toolkit, it comes with a bunch of modules.

One of the modules(expo-av) lacks a functionality that I'm interested. Therefore I'd like to some code into it, but I'm not yet comfortable contributing it because it's generic enough.

The module is called "expo-av", and is somehow embeded into the expo project, [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-av) is a link.

My goal is to modify this module so I need to fork it, but questions come:

1. How does "expo-av" gets published, because in my package.json, I can directly take a dependency on "expo-av". I think I can just replaced it with my new git location, right?
2. What's the best practice to fork expo-av? I know about git track remote etc, but this is a folder within a git repo, it seems like a maintenance headache

Comment: Hey! Did you end up with good answers to those questions? I'm currently interested in doing the same, and I was wondering all this.

Funnyly enough, I also need to change the same Expo pacakge!

Comment: @Daniel, I didn't solve this monorepo problem, but I give up using expo-av and forked react-native-audiokit then modified it myself